# On some sites, the closing fence is visible if post ends immediately after a code block that has an empty line

Tags: bug, markdown, code-formatting, code-block

An example of the bug is shown in the screenshot below, which occurred while editing [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/216801/43319):

[image: screenshot of bug]

The issue goes away if a trailing line break is added.

A minimal reproduction of the bug:

- [Ask on Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)
- Enter ```` "```\ncode\n\nmore\n```" ```` so the input field looks like:

  ````
  ```
  code

  more code
  ```
  ````

Comment: I thought maybe the trailing line break was mandatory in CommonMark but that doesn't seem the case: https://spec.commonmark.org/0.29/#code-fence

Comment: @rene One could rightfully claim that a non-empty document without a trailing line break isn't POSIX compliant…

Comment: I tried reproducing this bug in the [formatting sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3122/349538), but I didn't manage to reproduce it.

Comment: @DonaldDuck Right, I also tried reproducing it here in the post itself, but couldn't. However, if you [ask a question on the Code Golf site](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) and type in ````"```\ncode\n\nmore\n```"```` it will manifest.

Comment: I'm only able to reproduce if the top line of the code block is empty; if the line immediately after the one with the first triple backtick has text in it, it goes away. Also, I'm unable to reproduce this on most sites, only on Code Golf.

Comment: @SonictheCuriouserHedgehog So you don't see [this](https://i.imgur.com/U3NT6it.png)?

Comment: Reproduced on [Code Review](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10789/52915), we encounter this every so often. Adding an extra newline helps.